# Is there any way to identify character styles with Apache POI xwpf documents?

Tags: java, apache-poi, xwpf, textstyle

[Here](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hwpf/usermodel/CharacterRun.html#getStyleIndex%28%29)  we see that Apache POI for "HWPF" (MS Word 2000 .doc) files has a method CharacterRun.getStyleIndex()... by which you can, it appears, identify the **character** style(s) (not paragraph styles) which apply to this run...

But with the [XWPF](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFRun.html) stuff (MS Word 2003+ .docx) files, I can't find any way to identify the character style(s) in an XWPFRun object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should get all styles from all runs[1] within the `XWPFDocument` and print their XML if they are applied as character styles:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTRPr;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STStyleType;

import java.util.List;

public class WordGetRunStyles {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("This is a Test.docx");
  XWPFDocument xdoc = new XWPFDocument(fis);

  List<XWPFParagraph> paragraphs = xdoc.getParagraphs();
  for (XWPFParagraph paragraph : paragraphs) {
   List<XWPFRun> runs = paragraph.getRuns();
   for (XWPFRun run : runs) {
    CTRPr cTRPr = run.getCTR().getRPr();
    if (cTRPr != null) {
     if (cTRPr.getRStyle() != null) {
      String styleID = cTRPr.getRStyle().getVal();
      System.out.println("Style ID=====================================================");
      System.out.println(styleID);
      System.out.println("=============================================================");
      XWPFStyle xStyle = xdoc.getStyles().getStyle(styleID);
      if (xStyle.getType() == STStyleType.CHARACTER) {
       System.out.println(xStyle.getCTStyle());
      }
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

[1] please don't try it with a document with much content ;-).

As mentioned in the comment from @mike rodent, if you get `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openxmlformats/schemas/*something*` then you must use the full ooxml-schemas-1.3.jar as mentioned in https://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10025.

For me this code runs without this since I don't use `Phonetic Guide Properties` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.rubyproperties.aspx). I use Office 2007.

Comment: Thanks... well done.  There's something quite annoying going on here, though.  I had myself stumbled on this `XWPFRun.getCTR()` method... and when I tried to use it I got: "NoClassDefFoundError: ... org/openxmlformats/schemas/wordprocessingml/x2006/main/CTRuby".  It appeared that, although I had included all the jars from the POI 3.13 dload, I was missing some dependency(ies).  It turns out that this is ooxml-schemas-1.0.jar, available from Maven, for example.  I'm intrigued why you didn't mention that you had had to make use of this jar... (maybe it was in your path already).

Comment: @mike rodent: please see my supplements. Btw.: "I'm intrigued why you didn't mention that...". If I would be you I would think about the manner I will react on people who provide help without any quid.

Comment: No offence meant... I *was* intrigued (for me this adjective does not imply criticism of yourself) and now I know the answer.  I was "annoyed" not at yourself but at Apache... why on **Earth** don't they have a note on this when someone downloads the POI package?  It actually took some time for me to work out that I needed this extra jar... because there are already 2 jars called "poi-ooxml..." and a directory called "ooxml-lib" in the download!

Comment: PS the problem here appears to be that that Apache FAQ doesn't show up at all when you search (as I did) on ""NoClassDefFoundError: ... org/openxmlformats/schemas/wordprocessingml/".  Including that "wordprocessingml" bit at the end was the reason I failed to get directed to their FAQs!